# Two divs with same height ( styled-components )

Tags: css, flexbox, styled-components

So, i'm trying to get my left div to be the same height as the right div, just let me show the code ( i did in react.js ) and the styles

This is the structure

```
<FlexBoxModal>
                <FlexBoxMPhoto onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}>
                  <img src={sp.photo} />
                </FlexBoxMPhoto>
                <FlexBoxMComments
                  onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}
                ></FlexBoxMComments>
              </FlexBoxModal>
```

My styles

```
export const FlexBoxModal = styles.div`

max-width: 70%;
min-width: 50%;
height: 605px;

margin: auto;
margin-top: 3rem;
margin-bottom: 4rem;

overflow-y: hidden;
overflow-x: auto;

display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;

background: red;

`;

export const FlexBoxMPhoto = styles.div`

flex: 1.25;

display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: flex-end;

img{
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 70%;
    min-height: 300px;
    max-height: 605px;
    object-fit: cover;
}

`;

export const FlexBoxMComments = styles.div`

flex: .75;

width: 100%;
min-height: 300px;
max-height: 605px;

background: white;

`;
```

**The Problem** : i've thinking how to can i make this work, but i really don't know where to start, i fixed mi left div so i can position the img between a min-size and max-size, but, how can i make mi right div follow the height of my left div ? Let me show you this output

[Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWzfb.png)

**What i want** : So, as you can see, the white div isn't the same height ad the other one, how can i make that happen? both with same height?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The `FlexBoxModal` container that you have has align-items set to `center`. Switch that to `stretch`. That's the container that controls both the children.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but know, the white div takes all the space always

Comment: Do you have the image on a server so you can share the image link? I think it'll be easier with the correct photo in the equation.

Comment: Yes, but that's the problem, in the app, the user upload images/videos with differents sizes

But, i'm nearly getting to a solution !